# Can I add a \for field in a report style?

Tags: titles, report

I'm using a report class, which works just fine. On the title page I have listed the author, but I'm doing it for someone else.  Like writing a memo, it would be nice to put in a field, something like `\for` that then prints who the report is for.  Is it possible to create/add such?

Comment: there's nothing to stop you writing that code, provided you understand the innards of `report.cls`  (personally, i would put such stuff in an extra line of title.  not that i write that stuff much, any nore.)

Comment: The title formatting in the standard classes is intentionally very simple, so you could add that or more simply just use `\thanks`

Comment: And where should this or command typeset its argument? After the author and before the date? If you say `\for{Some Person}` what do you expect to see in the document (for example, "For: Some Person")?

Comment: I realise that the goal is to keep it simple, however most reports would be written by "someone" for "another person" so it would be nice to have "Author: Someone", newline "For: Another Person".

Answer (score 3):

It isn't as complicated as you might have thought:

```
\documentclass{report}
\title{Jingle--Jangle Jellyfish}
\author{From: Dr. Watson \\To: Sherlock Holmes}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```

[image: jinglejanglejellyfish]